# Retrieving the data from the response REST API

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a function in ajax that is responsible for sending mail to the REST API

```
function changeEmail() {
    var changeEmailDTO = { "email":$('#email').val()};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/changeEmail',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(changeEmailDTO),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

This data is received by the controller which validates this data

```
@PutMapping(value = "/changeEmail", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public HttpEntity<ChangeEmailDTO> showChangeEMail(
        @RequestBody @Valid ChangeEmailDTO changeEmailDTO
) {
    System.out.println("Email: " + changeEmailDTO.getEmail());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(changeEmailDTO);
}
```

If the data is incorrect, throws an exception to the exception handler

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

    return processFieldErrors(fieldErrors);
}
```

Thanks to that I get errors in response to json in the form of a list https://zapodaj.net/7e359361ed05a.png.html
I do not know how I can get the data from this response in js / ajax and do something for them, for example, post on the page. I do not know how?

Comment: `ajax` function accepts a property called `error`, so just add that next to you're `success` and handle it (`error: function (error) { console.log(error); }`).

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax call like below and then can append the value via the jquery dom

```
function changeEmail() {
    var changeEmailDTO = { "email":$('#email').val()};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/changeEmail',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(changeEmailDTO),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(xhr.status);
           $("#error-div").html(thrownError);---> example
           alert(thrownError);
  }


    });
}
```